# Can Can selectively cache abilities

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, ruby-2.0

I know about caching the whole `current_ability`.

Something like

```
def current_ability
  cached_ability = Rails.cache.read("#{current_user.cache_key}::ability")
  if cached_ability.present?
    ability = Marshal.load( cached_ability )
  else
    ability = super
    Rails.cache.write("#{current_user.cache_key}::ability", Marshal.dump( ability ))
  end
  @current_ability = ability
end
```

But is there is a way to cache a single ability ?
for example I do this :

```
Rails.cache.fetch("#{user.cache_key}::comments::ability") do
  can :manage, Comment, :article_id => articles_ids
end
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  Just found your post and am curious as well.

Comment: Not actually, but I ended up overriding `current_ability`. Look at my answer

Comment: Have you tried to cache the whole current_ability with cancancan ? I got marshal dump error; cancancan 2.0  and dalli 3.7.6 , ruby 2.4 and rails 5.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this to cache the whole `current_ability` object

In `ApplicationController`

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability = Rails.cache.fetch("#{current_user.cache_key}::ability") do
    super
  end
end unless Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: I get can't dump hash with default proc error using this.