# CanCanCan, How to store current_ability in memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan, dalli

After upgrading CanCan 1.4 to CanCanCan 2.0, I can not anymore cache `current_ability` into memcached with `Dalli`.

I got error below :

```rb
Cache write: profils/11-20170821121414000000::ability
Marshalling error for key 'development:profils/11-20170821121414000000::ability': can't dump hash with default proc
You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.1/gems/dalli-2.7.6/lib/dalli/server.rb:414:in `dump'
```

I store `current_ability` in memcached through Dalli by overriding `CanCan.Ability::current_ability` in **app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```rb
 def current_ability
     Rails.cache.fetch("#{current_user.profil.cache_key}::ability") do
       super
     end
 end
```

## Why I store current_ability in cache ?

cancan slowing down page loads, Because I have a lot of custom actions in many controllers, each page reload all abilities...

Any pointers in regards to cacheing / optimizing / best practices would be most appreciated. Thanks!

## update 1

**Add app/models/ability.rb**

```
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
     alias_action :edit, :to => :read
     role = user.profil

     if role.label == 'administrateur'
       can :manage, :all
     else
       role.rights.each do |right|
         model = right.resource.constantize rescue nil
         next unless model
         [:read, :create, :update, :destroy].each do |capability|
           can capability, model if right.send("#{capability}?")
         end
       end
       # Custom actions
       can([:collective, :collective_week, :presence, :day_details, :day_details_json], Movement) if can?(:read, Movement)
       can(:quick_add, Movement) if can?(:create, Movement)
       can([:actions, :set_action, :choose, :previous, :families_addresses, :ios,:families_members,:potential_relationships,:list_families,:list_decisions], Person) if can?(:read, Person)
       can(:addresses, Family) if can?(:read, Family)
       ...
       ...
       ...
     end
   end
end
```

## Update 2

Print an object of Ability (below is just a snippet of ability but the stucture is the same) That's the data that I try to store in memcached :

```
#<Ability:0x000000093030a0
 @aliased_actions={:read=>[:index, :show, :edit], :create=>[:new], :update=>[:edit]},
 @expanded_actions=
  {[:index, :show, :edit]=>[:index, :show, :edit]},
 @rules=
  [#<CanCan::Rule:0x00000008fb3e18
    @actions=[:read],
    @base_behavior=true,
    @block=nil,
    @conditions={},
    @match_all=false,
    @subjects=[AcceptanceReason(id: integer, label: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, institution_position: integer, acceptance_number: integer, department_type_id: integer)]>,
   #<CanCan::Rule:0x00000008fb3760
    @actions=[:create],
    @base_behavior=true,
    @block=nil,
    @conditions={},
    @match_all=false,
    @subjects=[AcceptanceReason(id: integer, label: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, institution_position: integer, acceptance_number: integer, department_type_id: integer)]>],
 @rules_index=
  {AcceptanceReason(id: integer, label: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, institution_position: integer, acceptance_number: integer, department_type_id: integer)=>[0, 1, 2, 3],
   Activity(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, institution_id: integer, label: string, activity_type_id: integer, employee_id: integer, department_id: integer, group_id: integer, beginning_at: date, ending_at: date, location: text, comments: text, objectif: text, evaluation: text, colour: string, collective_intervention_mean_id: integer, collective_intervention_status_id: integer, archive: boolean, activity_beginning_time: time, activity_ending_time: time, moyens_materiels: text, transports: text, autres_intervenants: text, budget: text, frequency: string)=>
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 645],
   ActivityCode(id: integer, label: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)=>[8, 9, 10]}
```

Comment: Why do you use an instance variable there? Try `def current_ability; Rails.cache.fetch(...) { super }; end`

Comment: Even I remove the instance variable, the same error is always there.

Comment: can you provide your ability initialization? maybe its return value is not serializable and that causes the error.

Comment: @xlembouras, Thank you for your attention, I updated my question.

Comment: I can't see something wrong... Make sure you reload your environment. Restart spring, rails server and memcached in case there is something broken there.

If that doesn't work, try to manually marshal dump and load ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849482/can-can-selectively-cache-abilities )

Comment: interesting, can you also print the content of ability `rules`?

Comment: @coorasse, Thank you for your attention, I updated my question